# Can I prevent system from invoking cmd.exe if the supplied program is not found?

Tags: windows, perl, shell, system, cmd

On Windows (with AcitveState perl 5.8...), when I use [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) to invoke another program from my perl script like this:

```
my $command="tool.exe"; # or 'C:\fullpath\tool.exe'
my $param = '...';
my $err = system($command, $param);
die("tool not found!") if $err == -1; # never used!
my $errno = $err>>8;
print "Command executed with error code: $errno\n";
```

I never can properly determine whether tool.exe can be found by system, because if it isn't found (isn't on the path, or the full path specified doesn't exist) `system` will apparently automatically pass the command off to cmd.exe, which then will fail with <strike>either path-not-found (exit code 3) or with command-not-found</strike> exit code 1!

As you can see, there are *no* shell metacharacters on the command I specify, so I'm a bit confused how the shell gets in there.

Also note that I have checked (with ProcessExplorer) that when the tool.exe is on the path, *no* cmd.exe will be involved, i.e. perl.exe will be the direct parent process of tool.exe.

### Workaround: (??)

The following will at least get me an exit code of `255`if the command doesn't exist, although it appears to be a bit hacky, as it will print `Can't spawn "cmd.exe": No such file or directory at ...` to STDERR.

```
my $command="tool.exe"; # or 'C:\fullpath\tool.exe'
my @args = ($command, '...');
my $err = system {$command} @args;
# die("tool not found!") if $err == -1; # never used!
my $errno = $err>>8;
die("tool not found!") if $errno == 255;
print "Command executed with error code: $errno\n";
```

Comment: Did you check the documentation of the system (`perldoc system`)?

Comment: @Dimitar: I *linked* to it above. It explicitly states "... the argument is checked for shell metacharacters, and if there are any, the entire argument is passed to the system's command shell ...". I do not see any shell metacharacters in my code.

Comment: Does the `` syntax works in Windows?

Comment: @Dimitar Petrov - yes it does. As well as pipe open for both sides.

Comment: @Dimitar: Yes, Backticks/qx/`` work on windows, but I need the behaviour of `system`, not `qx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don'tyou use the perl file exist check?

```
if( -e $file_path)  
{  
  #invoke the command  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet will be to use [`File::Which`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/file-which/)

```
use File::Which;
my $exe_path = which('tool.exe');
print "tool.exe not in path" unless $exe_path;
```

Comment: This, as well as cppcoder's answer, is certainly a useful workaround. However, I find it rather weird that cmd.exe seems to always be invoked by this perl implementation and really had hoped someone could shed some light on this.